# Javascript filter values of nested objects / arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am trying to filter an nested object for values, and rebuild it based on the results. I had a lot of trouble travelling trough the object but I came close this far. The object looks like this:

```
var files = {
    "All": [
        {
            "isPublic": true,
            "Files": [
                {
                  "Filename": "A",
                  "Download": true
                },
               {
                  "Filename": "B",
                  "Download": true
                }
            ]
        },
       {
            "isPublic": true,
            "Files": [
                {
                  "Filename": "A",
                  "Download": true
                }
            ]
        },
      {
            "isPublic": false,
            "Files": [
                {
                  "Filename": "C",
                  "Download": false,
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
};
```

I would like to find all files with a filename in this array:

```
var filenames = ["A","C"];
```

I tried (ES5):

```
test = files['All'].filter(function (obj) {
  return obj.Files.some(function (file) {
    if(arr.includes(file.Filename)) {
      return file.Filename;
    }
  });
});

console.log(test);
```

The result is:

```
[[object Object] {
  Files: [[object Object] {
  Download: true,
  Filename: "A"
}, [object Object] {
  Download: true,
  Filename: "B"
}],
  isPublic: true
}, [object Object] {
  Files: [[object Object] {
  Download: true,
  Filename: "A"
}],
  isPublic: true
}, [object Object] {
  Files: [[object Object] {
  Download: false,
  Filename: "C"
}],
  isPublic: false
}]
```

This works like a charm when there only is one filename in `Files`. But as you can see in the first object, sometimes there are multiple filenames. There it fails, because in the result B is also returned. The following part should not be returned.

```
[object Object] {
      Download: true,
      Filename: "B"
    }],
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

I opened a JS-bin here: https://jsbin.com/goyamumuve/1/edit?js,console

Comment: _"I tried filter, loops into loops, maps, etc"_ Please show your attempt. You should check [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: can you show us the expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to filter the Files arrays, or filter the top level array by inclusion in the Files arrays?

Comment: How is this related to JSON? The code isn't valid JSON, even without `var files = ` and `;`

Comment: I've editted the question

Comment: I recommend asking a new question. This question is downvoted, closed, answered and has an accepted answer. It's not possible to add an answer (because it's closed) and most people think, the problem here is solved (because of the accepted answer).

Comment: Thanks Jabaa, you are right. Alex updated his answer and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check arrays in Files property:

```
files['All'].filter(obj => obj.Files.some(file => file.Filename === "A"));
```

**Update**:

If you need avoid files from nested arrays that not match you condition - filter nested array.

```
const filteredFiles = files['All'].map(item => {
  const files = item.Files.filter(file => file.Filename === 'A');
  return files.lenght ? {...item, Files: files} : null;
}).filter(item => Boolean(item));
```

Comment: What is `any`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Typo from another language. I mean Array.prototype.some. Fixed

Comment: @AlexGor that helped a lot, thank you! I have one small issue left. It finds to many results. I've editted the question. Do you perhaps have a suggestion?

Comment: @AlexGor Thanks, really appreciated!